# Prevent Truncating of Leading Zeros in MS Access vba Import

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I used the code below to import CSV files from a local folder then into a table in Access.
However, I noticed the Leading Zeros are missing/truncated.

Not sure why as I was under the impression that Access did not cut off the zeros.

I tried padding with zeros but not working. I am thinking the leading zeros are being truncated during import into access and since this is happening by code, not sure how to stop it.

Hopefully the great pros here can take a look:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub ImportFileProcedure()
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim xlApp As Object, xlWb As Object, xlWs As Object
Dim lngRow As Long, lngLastRow As Long
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
strPath = "C:\FOLDER\"
strTable = "TEMP_TBL"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTable)
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPathFile)
        Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets(1)
        lngLastRow = xlWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
            rst.AddNew
            rst("SAMPLE") = xlWs.Range("A" & lngRow).Value
            rst("SAMPLE") = xlWs.Range("B" & lngRow).Value
            rst("SAMPLE") = xlWs.Range("C" & lngRow).Value
            rst("SAMPLE") = xlWs.Range("D" & lngRow).Value
            rst("SAMPLE") = xlWs.Range("E" & lngRow).Value
            rst.Update
        Next
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWb = Nothing
    Set xlWs = Nothing
    strFile = Dir()
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks for looking

Comment: What is the data type of the column in Access where you're importing the data that's getting truncated? If it's a numeric type, it will truncate leading zeroes. You need a column of data type string or something like that.

Comment: The data type is set to Text. Thanks, I was hoping this would prevent the truncate.

Comment: I am running an additional update query to add the leading zeros but I was hoping there was a way to do it all in one code rather than separate queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to simply create an UPDATE query that adds/pads the leading zeros, the UPDATE is run after the data becomes loaded into the table. This was the best I could do rather than modifying the above code:

This is SQL for the UPDATE Query:

```
x = left(yourfield & string(8,"0"), 8)

x = right(string(8,"0")& yourfield, 8)

or...

padlen = 8

x = left(yourfield & string(padlen,"0"), padlen)

x = right(string(padlen,"0")& yourfield, padlen)
```

Thanks everyone!